# How to force Wine to open a png file by the default image viewer of my Linux system?

Tags: wine, file-association

How to change the default program which opens a file type (for example a `.png` file) within Wine?

When I try to open a `png` file within Wine by an email client (installed under Wine), the default Wine program which is supposed to open `png` files is used (instead of the default image viewer of my Linux System).

I would rather prefer to open a `.png` file with the default program of my Linux system which handles `.png` files.

My Linux system open `png` files by `GPicView`. When I click on a `png` file, GPicView opens them without problem. When working by Wine programs, I would prefer to open `png` files by `GPicView` as well.

**To reproduce the problem:**
For example when I execute the Windows version of Alpine Email Client using Wine (see http://alpine.x10host.com/) when I try to open a `.png` email attachment, Alpine try to open it with `Wine Internet Explorer` which fails (no image can be seen when Internet Explorer opens).

To be precise, I use Lubuntu 18.04, Wine version is 3.0

**Other observation**: When I try to open a `pdf` attachment by Alpine, the default pdf viewer of my system (which is `Document Viewer` (Evince Authors)). This shows that the problem comes from Wine and not my Email Client. It seems that as Wine on my system seems to lack support for opening pdf files, it opens it by the default program of my system.

Answer (score 1):

First create a .reg file for example `png.reg` and type the following in it:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png]
@="PNGfile"
"Content Type"="image/png"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PNGfile\Shell\Open\command]
@="/bin/sh run_linux_program gpicview \"%1\""
```

Then import the .reg file into the registry using

```
regedit [Address to your file]/png.reg
```

for more information take a look at [this](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_associate_a_native_program_with_a_file_type_in_Wine.3F).
Please note that wine isn't installed on my machine so I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you. There was a typo in your code: pgicview --> gpicview, After correcting the typo, I used your solution but it didn't work. But your idea of using registry gave me the opportunity to find another solution.

Comment: @Name I fixed the typo. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run `regedit` from Terminal.

Find all occurrences of

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome`

and replace them with

`"C:\windows\system32\winebrowser.exe" -nohome`